# How to discover what codepage to use when converting RTF hex literals to Unicode

Tags: unicode, ms-word, rtf, codepages, word-2003

I'm parsing RTF 1.5+ files generated by Word 2003+ that may have content from other languages. This content is usually encoded as hex literals (\'xx). I would like to convert these literals to unicode values.

I know my document's code page by looking for ansicpg (\ansi\ansicpg1252).

When I use the ansicpg codepage to decode to Unicode, many languages (like French) seem to convert to the Unicode char values that I expect.

However when I see Russian text (like below), codepage 1252 decodes the content to jibberish.

\f277\lang1049\langfe1033\langnp1049\insrsid5989826\charrsid6817286 
\'d1\'f2\'f0\'e0\'ed\'e8\'f6\'fb \'e1\'e5\'e7 \'ed\'e0\'e7\'e2\'e0\'ed\'e8\'ff. \'dd\'f2
\'e0 \'f1\'f2\'f0\'e0\'ed\'e8\'f6\'e0 \'ed\'e5 \'e4\'ee\'eb\'e6\'ed\'e0 
\'ee\'f2\'ee\'e1\'f0\'e0\'e6\'e0\'f2\'fc\'f1\'ff \'e2 \'f2\'e0\'e1\'eb\'e8\'f6\'e5 
\'e2 \'f1\'ee\'e4\'e5\'f0\'e6\'e0\'ed\'e8\'e8.

I assume that lang1049, langfe1033, langnp1049 should provide me clues so I can programmatically choose a *different* (non-default) code page for the text that they reference? If so, where can I find information that explains how to map a lang* code to a codepage? Or should I be looking for some other RTF command/directive to provide me with the information I'm looking for? (Or must I use \f277 as a font reference and see if it has an associated codepage?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\lang` really only marks up particular stretches of the text as being in a particular language, and shouldn't impact what code page is to be used for the old non-Unicode `\'` escapes.

Putting an `\ansicpg` token in the header should perhaps do it, but seems to be ignored by Word (for both raw bytes and `\'` escapes.

> Or must I use \f277 as a font reference and see if it has an associated codepage?

It looks that way. Changing the `\fcharset` of the font assigned to a particular stretch of text is the only way I can get Word to change how it treats the bytes, anyway. The codes in this token (see eg [here](http://latex2rtf.sourceforge.net/rtfspec_6.html) for list) are, aggravatingly, different again from either the language ID or the code page number.

Comment: Thank you Bobince - that's exactly the tip I needed. You are right, the entire process is awkward, complicated, and aggravating.

Answer (score 1):

It is not so clear but you can use the RichEdit control in order to convert the RTF to UTF-8 format according to the MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774304(v=vs.85).aspx
Take a look to the SF_USECODEPAGE for the EM_STREAMOUT message.